Fastlane setup_ci for GitHub
Please note: this issue has been reported many times in other questions, but in each of those cases you will see that the solution was to clear the cached Derived Data. I have already done this, and have determined the problem to be a locked Keychain on my GitHub Action runner. So even though this sounds like a duplicate question, it is merely the same problem being reported but due to a unique cause not otherwise reported in those other questions. This question is not a dupe!

I'll repeat one more time for good measure: I have already cleared my cached Derived Data via rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*, and the problem has not gone away!
I have an iOS project (React Native under the hood) that I am building with Fastlane. Locally on my Mac it builds just fine, produces the IPA file, and I am able to upload the IPA to the App Store Connect and test it without any issues.
I am now trying to create an automated "CI" build for it using GitHub Actions. However when I run the same Fastlane command from GitHub, it freezes indefinitely at the [CP] Embed Pods Frameworks step (a build phase script that kicks off near the end of the build process).
This problem was reported here in this GitHub issue, where the OP reported they were able to fix the issue by unlocking the system Keychain on GitHub via Fastlane's setup_ci command.
So I have attempted to add the command at the front of my lane like so:
platform :ios do
  desc "Description of your lane"
  lane :staging do
    puts "iOS staging build"
    before_all do
      setup_ci
    end
    clean_build_artifacts
    disable_automatic_code_signing(path: "./ios/myapp.xcodeproj")
    build_app(
      scheme: "myapp",
      workspace: "./ios/myapp.xcworkspace",
      export_options: {
        signingStyle: "manual",
        provisioningProfiles: {
          "com.myapp" => "dc8421d4-d9f6-4357-925d-64a89c929734",
          "com.myapp.application" => "Distribution",
          "com.myapp.application.AB24Intents" => "AB24Intents",
          "com.myapp.application.ABRPWidget" => "ABRPWidget"
        }
      },
      clean: true
    )
  end
end

However the problem persists. I am sure I am simply not using or configuring setup_ci correctly. In that GH issue the reporter mentioned they needed to "use Match with a private GitHub repo", which: (1) I don't know what that means!; and (2) I haven't obviously configured yet.
Can anyone help me understand what setup_ci does, how it is configured to "use Match with a GH private repo", and most importantly how it unlocks the system Keychain for my build, so I can actually understand why it fixes my problem?
Thanks in advance for any-and-all help here!

I'm not familiar with Fastlane but I was curious and asked chat gpt 4 for some insights about your issue and the answer seems to make sense to me through the ruby configuration and github actions workflow file suggested. Did you try a similar approach yet?

Thanks @GuiFalourd (+1) but where would I run fastlane match init, and then all the other fastlane match * commands from? Inside the GitHub Action YAML or locally? If locally, why (?!) and how do I "pass" my certificates into those fastlane match commands?

For what I understood, you need to use those fastlane commands to generate the certificates locally and set the profile in the git repository. Then those certificates generated locally should be saved as secrets on GitHub, to be accessed during a Github Actions workflow execution, based on the profile set on the github repository (that will be available on the workflow thanks to the actions/checkout that will get the repository files). Does it make sense?

Yeah that makes sense, thank you! However, I really don't love the idea of putting certificates in a GitHub repo. To your knowledge, can match be used with other data sources, such as an S3 bucket?

It seems to be possible to use s3 through fastlane by using fastlane match import --storage-mode=s3 (in can also be configured in the Matchfile by using the storage_mode field). Some references about s3 usage can be found here

I think you are missing the match on your code take a look here
